# error while run the pipeline for sonar quality gate status

Tags: azure-devops

## Starting: sonar quality-gate status-PowerShell

## Task         : PowerShell
Description  : Run a PowerShell script on Linux, macOS, or Windows
Version      : 2.194.0
Author       : Microsoft Corporation
Help         : https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/powershell

Generating script.
========================== Starting Command Output ===========================
"C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -NoLogo -NoProfile -NonInteractive -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Command ". 'C:\Users\vmforapiadmin\Documents\devops\ado-agent\agent\test_temp\790b5a05-820f-41fb-9e36-f308835ce941.ps1'"
System.PullRequest.PullRequestId : The term 'System.PullRequest.PullRequestId' is not recognized as the name of a
cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify
that the path is correct and try again.
At C:\Users\vmforapiadmin\Documents\devops\ado-agent\agent\test_temp\790b5a05-820f-41fb-9e36-f308835ce941.ps1:9
char:151

- ... Base_Analytics&PullRequest=$(System.PullRequest.PullRequestId)"  -Hea ...
- ```
                               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  ```

  - CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (System.PullRequest.PullRequestId:String) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordE
    xception
  - FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

##[error]PowerShell exited with code '1'.
Finishing: sonar quality-gate status-PowerShell

Comment: anyone tell me the solution for it

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation - This variable is initialized only if the build ran because of a Git PR affected by a branch policy.

Have you disabled direct commit to Main ? Then if you initiate a pull request and use the variable it should work.